# How to Stream Through Large Amounts of Twitter Data?

Tags: asp.net, twitter

I'll be working on a project that will require a live output of a number of tweets users have hash tagged on Twitter as well as their tweets. Something along the lines of MTV's Twitter Tracker: http://vma-twittertracker.mtv.com/live/#buzz.

What intrigued me about this site is how can they constantly make API calls to Twitter without breaching the request limit?

I'd appreciate if anyone could guide me on the most effective way to accomplish this. From the research I've carried out thus far, I presume I will need to use Twitter's Streaming API.

Since there is a chance that the number of tweets output to my page could be in their thousands (AJAX loaded) along with stats on number of retweets/favourites, what would be the most scalable approach within my .NET site? Any examples or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your responses.

It looks like sites such that display a lot of Twitter stats/data use [third party approved providers](https://dev.twitter.com/programs/twitter-certified-products/products#Certified-Data-Products) that have direct access to [Twitter's Firehose API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/firehose).

I have managed to get in contact with an approved provider to supply us with the feeds of data required (and it ain't cheap!).

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Linq2Twitter](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com).  It is a great wrapper around the Twitter API, and provides two mechanisms that will help you:

- There is a search function that allows you to search for hash tags, etc, which will limit the amount of data you are getting back
- You have the option to specify getting all the data since a certain tweet ID.  You can therefore incrementally search the feed by performing searches and searching, in subsequent calls, from the ID you left off on.

I have used this many times to search the public feed and have not had any issues to date.  I think the search function is key not requesting too much.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I would like to find a way to get tweet information without using a third party library. From what I have been reading on the Twitter API forums, its recommended that I use the their streaming API.

Answer (score 1):

you can look into Storm framework. Below are few links for further reference:-

http://storm-project.net/

https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm